# Print a list of values in a function but also need to return it

Tags: python

I have two separate functions. For one of them, I need to print the answer which is a list of values, but I also need to return it so I can use in the second file.
This is the first function:

```
def flo( rate, length, interval):
    final = []
    new  = [rate[i:i+ length] for i in range(0, len( rate)-len( rate) %  length , length)]
    for i in range(len(new )):
        final.append('True')
        print(final)
    return final
  

status( rate, length, interval, threshold)
```

The output for this is:

```
[False]
[False, False]
[False, False, True]
[False, False, True, True]
[False, False, True, True, True]
[False, False, True, True, True, False]
[False, False, True, True, True, False, True]
[False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True]
[False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False]
```

I need the output of this to import it inside another function. So I did:

```
import flo  

def find ( status, min_seg):
    newlist = []
    start = 0
    end = 0
    x = [index for index, ele in enumerate(disorder_status) if ele]           # to find the index of elements 'True'
    for index,value in enumerate(x):
        if index < len(x)-1:
            if x[index+1]> value+1:
                end = index +1
                newlist.append(x[start:end])
                start = end
        else:
            newlist.append(x[start: len(x)])
    for l in newlist:
        if len(l)>=min_segment: 
            y = []
            y = [l[0],len(l)]
            print(y)

z = flow(flow_rate, length, interval, threshold)            

find (z,min_segment)
```

But the answer I am given is this:

```
 x = [index for index, ele in enumerate(disorder_status) if ele]           # to find the index of elements 'True'

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Is there any way to fix this because if I return the value, then my output is [False] but I need the list.

Comment: This cannot be your code.  You are printing every time you go through the loop, so it should print `[False]`, `[False, False]`, `[False, False, True]`, `[False, False, True, True]`, and so on.  Further, you ARE returning the final list.  So, your code cannot look like what you say here.

Comment: @Tim Roberts I did return the final list but when I try to import it, I get:      
```[False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False]
None```

Comment: Not with that code, you didn't.  I literally tried it myself and it worked fine, as I knew it would.  You need to show us the EXACT code you're running that shows the problem, in a state where WE can run it and see what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import it to another file write like this

```
from filename import flow_rate_to_disorder_status as flow
```

OR if it is same file just write like this:

```
output = flow_rate_to_disorder_status(flow_rate, segment_len, interval, threshold) and then use this variable inside another function
```

Comment: I tried that but my output is: [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False]
None